# How can I distribute an iphone app to specific organization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-provisioning

We need to make some versions of an iphone app and do not want it to be publicly available. Is it possible to control this distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your clients are not from US, they should register for [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/), which will give them ability to distribute the app in-house without AdHoc distribution limitations.

Answer (score 6):

Apple now support B2B distribution. I'm not sure on the specifics of how it works, but have a look at this: http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/

Be aware that this is currently only available in the USA however the [Apple website](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/) currently says:

> Coming Soon. The App Store Volume Purchase Program is expanding to the following countries: Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Japan, New Zealand, Spain, and United Kingdom.

Comment: Good point, it does say that in the link, but I'll add it to my answer so it's more obvious.